# Check if a file exists irrespective of its type

Tags: bash

So I want to know if a given path exists (may not necessarily be a directory.) I know that you can test if a directory exists with `[ -d "$arg" ]`, but I want to know how to test if any path exists, not whether it is a directory. Can someone point me in the direction to where to look.

Comment: The place to look would be `man test`, which presents a list of all `test`, aka `[`, operators.

Answer (score 1):

That's what `-e` primary does (except for symlinks though, `test` builtin follows symbolic links and operate on the target of the link, rather than the link itself).

```
[ -e "$arg" ]
```

An alternative that works with symlinks as well (requires GNU find):

```
find "$arg" -quit 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: @user230493215 : See the section titled _CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS_ in the bash man page. Or just search the man page for `   -a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `ls`

```
ls $path &> /dev/null && echo 'yep' || echo 'nop'
```